# Finding which base number given operations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, complex-numbers, number-systems

$$ (35_a + 24_a) * 21_a = 1081_a $$

Which base is the above number?

Any advice on how to solve questions like these? I tried making it in to a polynomial:

$(3a+5 + 2a+4) * (2a+1) = 108a + 1$

$10a^2 + 23a + 9 = 108a + 1$

$10a^2 - 85a + 8 =0$

But the roots of that equation do not equal the base of that number, so I obviously did something wrong

Comment: Look at RHS, and think of what happens in base 10 for numbers with 3 or more digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea but you need to expand $1081_a$ as $(1+8a+0a^2+1a^3)$ Then solve for $a$.

Comment: I agree with you. With your approach, one get the equation $a^3-10a^2-15a-8=0$. Unfortunately, this has no positive integer solutions. There must be something else we are all missing

Comment: Why does the base need to be a positive integer?

Comment: @amcalde I've tried solving for that equation but there are no integer solutions, and I was told the answer is an integer. I feel like I must be doing something wrong in the expansion (multiplication step perhaps?) but can't figure out what.

Comment: @user120920 As written, I get an irrational answer. Also the base is less than 8 and an 8 appears in the original post so it would be an improper base anyhow. Couly there be a typo in the original?

Comment: @amcalde the assignment was just reposted today with different numbers, so it looks like it must have been a typo. Thank you for your help, sorry about that!