# For the following number, state the base represented as t?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, number-systems

$1011 \textrm{(base }t) = 4931 \textrm{(base 10)}$

I have to find $t$, which is the base of 1011.

I do the following:

$4931 \textrm{(base 10)} = 4 \times 10^3 + 9 \times 10^2 + 3 \times 10^1 + 1 \times 10^0$

$= 4000 + 900 + 30 + 1$

$= 4931$

$1011 \textrm{(base }t) = 1 \times t^3 + 0 \times t^2 + 1 \times t^1 + 1 \times t^0$

$= t^3 + 0 + t + 1$

$= t^3 + 1 + 1$

$t^3 + t + 1 = 4931$

$t^3 + t = 4930$

Is there a mistake made here? $t$ should equal the base but I have multiple solutions in this case.

I used a method similar to what is in this thread: [Finding which base number given operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932722/finding-which-base-number-given-operations?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $t^3 + t -4930 = 0$ has only one real solution, $t=17$.